# Inequality involving tensor product of orthonormal unit vectors

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices, inequalities

Let $e_1,...,e_r$ be the first $r$ standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n, r<n$. Let $u_1,...,u_n$ be another orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\otimes$ be the tensor product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as
$$S = span\{e_1\otimes e_1,...,e_r\otimes e_r\}$$
$\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, as a Hilbert space, is also equipped with the usual matrix inner product $\langle,\rangle$ and the induced norm $\|\|$ (which is the Frobenius norm).

Take any $\Lambda\in S$ with $\|\Lambda\|=1$. Is the following conjecture true?

There exists a constant $C\geq1$, if $u_1,...,u_n$ are chosen such that 
$$1 -\delta\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\langle\Lambda,u_i\otimes u_i\rangle\right|^2$$ for some very small $\delta>0$ (for example $0<\delta<\frac{1}{rn}$), then there exists a set $T\subset\{1,2,...,n\}$ with $|T| = r$ satisfying 
$$1-C\delta\leq\sum_{i\in T}\left|\langle\Lambda,u_i\otimes u_i\rangle\right|^2$$

The conjecture can be verified when $r=1$. Note that $C$ cannot depend on $\delta$, which means the conjecture states that there is a $C>0$ to make the assertion true for all $\delta$ small enough. For example, $C$ can be taken as 2 when $r=1$.

Comment: Sure. Let $C = 1$ and $T = \{1, \ldots, n\}.$

Comment: @VítTuček: they said $r < n$.

Comment: looks to be true for r=1

Comment: Take $C$ large enough to make $1-C\delta$ negative!

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan C should be a constant not depending on $\delta$... I'll make this clearer in the post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without loss of generality, $u_1,\dots,u_n$ can be taken to be the standard basis of ${\bf R}^n$ (so $e_1,\dots,e_r$ is just some arbitrary orthonormal system).  We can view $\Lambda$ as a real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix of Frobenius norm $1$ and rank at most $r$.  (Conversely, every such matrix has a representation of the desired form for some $e_1,\dots,e_r$ by the spectral theorem, so this reformulation has not lost any information.) If $D = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle \Lambda, u_i \otimes u_i \rangle u_i \otimes u_i$ is the diagonal component of $\Lambda$, the hypothesis is then $\|D\|^2 \geq 1-\delta$.

Let $\lambda = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r,0,\dots,0)$ be the diagonalisation of $\Lambda$ (the ordering of the eigenvalues is irrelevant), thus $\lambda$ is a unit vector supported on a set of $r$ indices in $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  By the [Schur-Horn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem), $D$ is a convex combination of the permutations $\sigma(\lambda)$ of $\lambda$, $\sigma \in S_n$, where the symmetric group $S_n$ acts on diagonal matrices in the obvious manner, thus
$$ D = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} c_\sigma \sigma(\lambda)$$
for some non-negative coefficients $c_\sigma$ summing to $1$.  (Again, the Schur-Horn theorem is an if-and-only-if statement, so we have still not lost any information so far.)

Now we exploit the uniform convexity of the Frobenius norm. We take the norm square
$$ 1-\delta \leq \|D\|^2 = \sum_{\sigma,\sigma' \in S_n} c_\sigma c_{\sigma'} \langle \sigma(\lambda), \sigma'(\lambda) \rangle$$
and then apply the cosine rule to conclude
$$ \sum_{\sigma,\sigma' \in S_n} c_\sigma c_{\sigma'} \| \sigma(\lambda) - \sigma'(\lambda)\|^2 \leq 2\delta$$
hence by pigeonholing there exists $\sigma_0 \in S_n$ such that
$$ \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} c_\sigma \| \sigma(\lambda) - \sigma_0(\lambda)\|^2 \leq 2\delta$$
hence by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$ \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} c_\sigma \| \sigma(\lambda) - \sigma_0(\lambda)\| \leq \sqrt{2\delta}$$
hence by the triangle inequality
$$ \| \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} c_\sigma \sigma(\lambda) - \sigma_0(\lambda)\| \leq \sqrt{2\delta}$$
thus
$$ \| D - \sigma_0(\lambda) \| \leq \sqrt{2\delta}.$$
The diagonal matrix $\sigma_0(\lambda)$ is supported on a set $T \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ of cardinality $r$, and the above inequality implies that the Frobenius norm of $D$ outside of $T$ is at most $\sqrt{2\delta}$.  Thus
$$ \sum_{i \not \in T} |\langle \Lambda, u_i \otimes u_i \rangle|^2 \leq 2\delta$$
so that
$$ \sum_{i \in T} |\langle \Lambda, u_i \otimes u_i \rangle|^2 \geq 1-3\delta$$
as required.

Comment: This proof is ingenious. Thank you Terry!